# What does this image represent? The number of lines is important

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image: image description]

A graphic with different lines on one side or the other and even on the middle.

Comment: The first tag is a bit inappropriate. This is pretty much a "you know or you don't" puzzle. There's no way to "logically deduce" the answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> It's Ogham. It reads Cristina (you read Ogham from bottom to top).
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogham

I used to be able to sight-read it.

Comment: No problem. I am, in fact, a massive geek. :)

Comment: Your massive geekiness saved me :D.

Comment: Is it just me or are the lines for `r` the wrong way round?

Comment: I noticed that when I translated it.

Comment: How are we supposed to know this?